# Doing a build when changes happen in either of two repositories AND a file system

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I have a ccnet project which watches two SVN repositories for changes. Using a source control block of type multi worked fine for that. Now the project needs to watch the two repositories and a file. It needs to only build if one of the two repositories changed **and** the file changed.

I tried nesting a multi source control block in a multi source control block as follows(you may ignore all the variables):

```
    <sourcecontrol type="multi">
        <requireChangesFromAll>True</requireChangesFromAll>
        <sourceControls>
        <sourcecontrol type="multi">
            <requireChangesFromAll>False</requireChangesFromAll>
            <sourceControls>            
                <filtered>              
                    <sourceControlProvider type="svn" autoGetSource="false">
                       <executable>$(svn-exe)</executable>
                       <timeout units="minutes">60</timeout>
                       <trunkUrl>$(svn-srcmwo)</trunkUrl>
                       <workingDirectory>$(mwo-localfull)</workingDirectory>
                    </sourceControlProvider>
                    <inclusionFilters>
                        <cb:mwo-include-filters/>                       
                    </inclusionFilters>
                </filtered>
                <filtered>
                    <sourceControlProvider type="svn" autoGetSource="false">
                        <executable>$(svn-exe)</executable>
                        <timeout units="minutes">10</timeout>
                        <trunkUrl>$(svn-orion)</trunkUrl>
                        <workingDirectory>$(orion-localfull)</workingDirectory>
                        <webUrlBuilder type="websvn">
                            <url>$(viewvc-orion){0}$(viewvc-config)</url>
                        </webUrlBuilder>
                    </sourceControlProvider>
                    <inclusionFilters>
                        <pathFilter>
                            <pattern>$(svn-orion-trunk)</pattern>
                        </pathFilter>
                    </inclusionFilters>
                    <exclusionFilters>
                        <pathFilter>
                            <pattern>$(svn-grsim-makfiles)</pattern>
                        </pathFilter>
                    </exclusionFilters>
                </filtered>             
            </sourceControls>               
        </sourcecontrol>
        <sourcecontrol type="filesystem">
            <repositoryRoot>e:\build_listen</repositoryRoot>
        </sourcecontrol>
      </sourceControls>
    </sourcecontrol>
```

but CCValidator gave the error:

**Unused node detected: <sourcecontrol type="filesystem"><repositoryRoot>e:\build_listen&lt/repositoryRoot></sourcecontrol>**

Does anyone see how this can be done - doing and AND on a file system and two repositories?

Comment: Your edits don't fix the problem. `<sourceControls>` is not supposed to be parent of `<requireChangesFromAll>` but to be its sibling. Why did you edit the sources anyway? How would one understand your question if the presented source code is correct?

Comment: The point of the edit was to correct the missing sourceControls element and nothing more. I want to keep my original post true to my original intent and line of thinking. I have implemented your solution and am waiting for verification that it is working in practice. I will mark answers then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This nested source control thing is quite complicated indeed. First of all you missed the `<sourceControls>` tag in the outer multi sourcecontrol block. Secondly there is an important note in the [CCNET documentation on multi sourcecontrol blocks](http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Multi_Source_Control):

> Note that, due to the way the configuration gets parsed, if you are using a "multi" block, then the items within the  element should not be  elements (as you may expect). Instead, the name of the element should be the same as you would put in the "type" attribute when using a  element.

That is just the way the source control blocks work in your existing configuration: `<filtered>` instead of `<sourcecontrol type="filtered">`.

So this should fix your problem:

```
<sourcecontrol type="multi">
  <requireChangesFromAll>True</requireChangesFromAll>
  <sourceControls>
    <multi>
      <requireChangesFromAll>False</requireChangesFromAll>
      <sourceControls>
        <filtered>
          <sourceControlProvider type="svn" autoGetSource="false">
            <executable>$(svn-exe)</executable>
            <timeout units="minutes">60</timeout>
            <trunkUrl>$(svn-srcmwo)</trunkUrl>
            <workingDirectory>$(mwo-localfull)</workingDirectory>
          </sourceControlProvider>
          <inclusionFilters>
            <cb:mwo-include-filters/>
          </inclusionFilters>
        </filtered>
        <filtered>
          <sourceControlProvider type="svn" autoGetSource="false">
            <executable>$(svn-exe)</executable>
            <timeout units="minutes">10</timeout>
            <trunkUrl>$(svn-orion)</trunkUrl>
            <workingDirectory>$(orion-localfull)</workingDirectory>
            <webUrlBuilder type="websvn">
              <url>$(viewvc-orion){0}$(viewvc-config)</url>
            </webUrlBuilder>
          </sourceControlProvider>
          <inclusionFilters>
            <pathFilter>
              <pattern>$(svn-orion-trunk)</pattern>
            </pathFilter>
          </inclusionFilters>
          <exclusionFilters>
            <pathFilter>
              <pattern>$(svn-grsim-makfiles)</pattern>
            </pathFilter>
          </exclusionFilters>
        </filtered>
      </sourceControls>
    </multi>
    <filesystem>
      <repositoryRoot>e:\build_listen</repositoryRoot>
    </filesystem>
  </sourceControls>
</sourcecontrol>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't have two following `sourcecontrol` blocks.
You should refactor your projects as follow:

1. One project with only the filesystem trigger.
   This will be the trigger for the next job
2. Another project linked to the previous one AND with your multi sourcecontrol triggers.

Have a look to [CruiseServer Control Task](http://emeaccnetmbt.emea.apc.com/cc_net/doc/CCNET/CruiseServer%20Control%20Task.html) to synchronize two jobs:

Comment: You're right and you're wrong. You can't have two consecutive `<sourcecontrol>` blocks. But if you put these blocks in a multi sourcecontrol block (as the OP intended) and adjust the node names according to the naming convention inside multi sourcecontrol blocks, it will work.

Comment: @TheChairman thx for the comments, this feature is quite complicated so I've missed something :)